# How to Set NULL value to declared variable in SELECT statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, set

I don't understand what is going on.

```
DECLARE @X DATETIME;

--FIRST
SELECT @X = ContractDate
FROM dbo.Foo C
WHERE ProjectCode = 120125 
  AND VersionID = (SELECT MIN(VersionID) 
                   FROM dbo.Foo 
                   WHERE ProjectCode = C.ProjectCode)

SELECT @X

--SECOND
SELECT @X = ContractDate
FROM dbo.Foo C
WHERE ProjectCode = 130192 
  AND VersionID = (SELECT MIN(VersionID) 
                   FROM dbo.Foo 
                   WHERE ProjectCode = C.ProjectCode)

SELECT @X
```

First 'SELECT @X' must return '2012-09-10', Second'SELECT @X' must return 'NULL' but Second returns '2012-09-10'.

**First question**: why doesn't the second 'SELECT @X' return NULL?

The code block above is in `WHILE` statement. The original code is here:

```
DECLARE @ProjectCode NVARCHAR(10)

DECLARE CRS CURSOR FOR
    SELECT P.ProjectCode
    FROM dbo.Foo P

OPEN CRS

FETCH NEXT FROM CRS INTO @ProjectCode

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ProjectContractDate_T0 DATETIME;

    SELECT @ProjectContractDate_T0 = ContractDate
    FROM dbo.FooFoo C
    WHERE ProjectCode = @ProjectCode 
      AND VersionID = (SELECT MIN(VersionID) 
                       FROM dbo.FooFoo 
                       WHERE ProjectCode = C.ProjectCode)

    SELECT @ProjectContractDate_T0

    FETCH NEXT FROM CRS INTO @ProjectCode
END

CLOSE CRS
DEALLOCATE CRS
```

While loop is processing:

- when `ProjectCode = 120125`, `@ProjectContractDate_T0` is '2012-09-10',

then next

- `Projectcode = 130192`, `@ProjectContractDate_T0` must be NULL but is '2012-09-10'.

How can it be?

In while loop, why didn't `ProjectContractDate_T0` reset to NULL?

Comment: you need to print out all values and debug ,i see this as data related  ,we dont have any idea on data involved

Comment: This is a classic 'procedural' approach to a relational database, is not constructive as illustrate bad code. It should be:

SELECT P.ProjectCode, C.ContractDate
FROM
    dbo.Foo P
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.FooFoo C
        ON(
                C.ProjectCode = P.ProjectCode
            AND C.VersionID   =(
                    SELECT MIN(VersionId)
                    FROM dbo.FooFoo C_Min
                    WHERE C_Min.ProjectCode = P.ProjectCode
                )

Answer (score 3):

When the where clause of the select filter out every records then no assignation is made. Therefore, @x has the value of the last time it was assigned.

Try this way instead :

```
SELECT @X = (SELECT ContractDate
             FROM dbo.Foo C
             WHERE ProjectCode = 130192 
             AND VersionID = (SELECT MIN(VersionID) 
                              FROM dbo.Foo 
                              WHERE ProjectCode = C.ProjectCode))
```

This way, your assignation "select" doesn't contains any where clause, thus it will always be executed. If the inner select doesn't result anything, then null is assigned to X.

Here is another example

```
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(25) = 'Initial value'

SELECT @x = 'Value1'
WHERE 0 = 1

--@x is still "Initial value" cause 0 isn't egal to 1

SELECT @x = (SELECT 'Value2'
             WHERE 0 = 1)

--@x is now null because the impossible where clause didn't hindered the assignation. It has just made the inner select to return null instead.
```

---

As Martin suggestion, you can instead reset the value before with

```
SELECT @X = null
```

but I prefer to have just one assignation select because it's shorter, and it is one less instruction line for the SQL Engine.

---

***Side note :***

Your "select" could be rewritten with an "Order by" and "TOP 1" clause to get the minimum. It's give the same result and is shorter to be write/read.

```
SELECT @ProjectContractDate_T0 = (SELECT TOP 1 ContractDate
                                  FROM dbo.FooFoo C
                                  WHERE ProjectCode = @ProjectCode 
                                  ORDER BY VersionID)
```

It does the same thing.

Comment: Yep, or just reinitilaise `@X` to null before the second select.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found out like your offer. I wrote :                                     SET @X = (SELECT ContractDate
             FROM dbo.Foo C
             WHERE ProjectCode = 130192 
             AND VersionID = (SELECT MIN(VersionID) 
                              FROM dbo.Foo 
                              WHERE ProjectCode = C.ProjectCode))                                          Thanks AXMIM, Martin

Comment: AXMIM, your side note is very usefull, thank a alot.

Answer (score 3):

When setting a variable in a select statement, if that select statement returns no rows, then there will be no assignment; your variable's value will not change.

As to your loop problem, the scope of a variable in T-SQL is the batch, not the loop. It is not re-declared or initialized with each iteration.

As such, it can be a good practice in T-SQL to explicitly initialize your variables to null when you otherwise might expect a re-initialization in a different language. This might make it more readable and better show your intent.

Also, I should add that cursors and loops in T-SQL are usually best avoided when a set-based solution (query) is possible, which is almost always. Obviously this depends on your use case, which wasn't stated.

Comment: 'As to your loop problem, the scope of a variable in T-SQL is the batch, not the loop. It is not re-declared or initialized with each iteration.'    I think the same. Thanks Tim.

Comment: "When setting a variable in a select statement, if that select statement returns no rows, then there will be no assignment; your variable's value will not change." - absolute gold - I always thought it would assign NULL